# Why I am having a this error on phpmyadmin: Error creating foreign key on revision (check data types)?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I´m trying to create Foreign Keys in phpmyadmin, but I get this error:

> Error creating foreign key on revision (check data types)

I don´t understand it because the data types are equal. So, what I want is to create a Foreign Key from 'acoustictreatment' to 'filterspecifications' which contains tag, offerid and revision. But I get the error that I mentioned.

This are my tables:

```
  CREATE TABLE `offer` (
  `projectid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `customer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `creator` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `revision` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
ALTER TABLE `offer`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`projectid`,`revision`); 



CREATE TABLE `filterspecifications` (
      `tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `gasFlow` double NOT NULL,
      `dustToHandle` double NOT NULL,
      `offerid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `selectedFilter` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `revision` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
    ALTER TABLE `filterspecifications`
          ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tag`,`offerid`,`revision`),
          ADD KEY `offerid` (`offerid`,`revision`);
        ALTER TABLE `filterspecifications`
        ADD CONSTRAINT `filterspecifications_ibfk_1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`offerid`,`revision`) REFERENCES `offer` (`projectid`, `revision`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;


CREATE TABLE `acoustictreatment` (
      `tag` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `offerid` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `outputFanSilencer` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      `fanAcousticInsulation` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
      `revision` int(11) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
    ALTER TABLE `acoustictreatment`
      ADD PRIMARY KEY (`tag`,`offerid`,`revision`);
```

Comment: In [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b8758c) it works fine

Comment: That´s the problem, that it should work well, but in phpmyadmin I get an error

Comment: There is no FK constraint in your code.

Comment: I know, because if I put it, it shows that error

Comment: What field to what field do you try to refer to?

Comment: Offer has to be created before you attempt to create a foreign key on it.

Comment: @Akina From tag, offerid and revision of acoustictreatment to tag, offerid and revision of filterspecifications

Comment: @P.Salmon It´s done like you say, that´s not the problem. I have put it on the wrong way in the question

Comment: I don't understand your last comment ,If the ALTER TABLE `filterspecifications` is the last statement in the code then there is no problem

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found is to delete the 'acoustictreatment' table and create it again with the foreign key from the beginning. Because what I was trying to do was to create all the tables and then create the foreign keys, but that didn´t work for me